# Why wasn't Anubis present on the day Horus got crowned?

Tags: plot-explanation, gods-of-egypt

All of the gods were at the ceremony at the Palace of Osiris in *Gods of Egypt*.
Horus was to be crowned as the new king of Egypt. All of the gods were present at that day, even though Set came a bit late.

**Question**: Why was Anubis not on the ceremony?
Had they forgotten about him at that point or was he just not invited (*giggles*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Anubis was never known to be involved much in other things than being Anubis:

> As the protector of the dead, who invented mummification and so the preservation of the body, he seems to have been considered too busy to have involved himself in the kinds of stories told about the other Egyptian gods. <sub>[1](https://www.ancient.eu/Anubis/)</sub>

As far as I can find, the role Anubis played in the movie is consistent with that. He's called upon to help souls journey through the afterlife and protects the afterlife against a demon. <sub>[2](http://gods-of-egypt.wikia.com/wiki/Anubis)</sub>

So, it makes a lot of sense that Anubis wasn't present at the coronation. By leaving him out, the makers of the movie stayed true to the character of Anubis. He was far too busy to make an appearance. He probably was sent an invitation but hadn't even had the time to read it yet.